# Select element scales cross-browser, except for IE8

Tags: html, css, resize

I'm trying to scale a `select`-element with the window-size (on resizing). This goes well for FF3.6, Chrome 10, IE6 (!!) and IE7, however... not for IE8.

A demonstration of the particular code-fragment can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/yKVbr/5/.
That is:
**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <select>
        <option value='field1'>Datum gereed</option>
        <option value='field2'>Korte omschrijving</option>
        <option value='field3'>Taak Code</option>
        <option value='field4'>Project omschrijving</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 96px;
    width: auto;
    width: -moz-availble;
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth-(10+96));
    top: 134px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

select {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    right: 90px;
    width: auto;
    width: -moz-available;
    width: expression(wrap.style.pixelWidth-(25+90)););
    top: -2px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

When IE8 renders in Quirksmode (i.e. without a DOCTYPE), it goes well because then it behaves like IE7. However, this is not a satisfiable solution :-)

I've searched through the forum, however I didn't find a similar problem.
I've also tried working with the CSS3-property `resize` (`resize:both; overflow:auto`) to no avail.

Who can help pointing me in the right direction so that all browsers still scale it correcly *including* IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

poepje pointed me in the right direction. The only thing that was missing was to keep the same amount of left and right position (because of the width-%).
Wrapping the `select` with another div, shows the intended result. IE8 *does* render `div` elements correctly concerning its left and right properties, so that most of the `select` style can be moved to the surrounding `div` and only setting `width:100%` for the select.

The new demo can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/yKVbr/8/, i.e.:
**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrap">
  **<div id="innerwrap">**
        <select>
            <option value='field1'>Datum gereed</option>
            <option value='field2'>Korte omschrijving</option>
            <option value='field3'>Taak Code</option>
            <option value='field4'>Project omschrijving</option>
        </select>
  **</div>**
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div#wrap {..same as before..}
div#innerwrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    right: 90px;
    width: auto;
    width: -moz-available;
    width: expression(wrap.style.pixelWidth-(25+90)););
    top: -2px;    
}

select {
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 96px;
    width: auto;
    width: -moz-availble;
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth-(10+96));
    top: 134px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:80%;
    height:20px;
}

select {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    right: 90px;
    width: auto;
    width: -moz-available;
    width: expression(wrap.style.pixelWidth-(25+90)););
    top: -2px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What i did here is use a percentage for the width. But keep in mind that only the width property can make use of the percentage element.

Comment: Thanks! This proved to work (almost)! Except it doesn't adhere to its left and right properties now, because it maintains a % for the width. See my answer, that yours led me to, that worked perfectly for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With left and right positioning, do you mean you want it centered? In that case i would try one of the following:

```
div#wrap { /* or innerwrap, whatever suits you best */
   margin: auto;
}
```

or

```
div#wrap {
   margin: x%; /* where the x is to be replaced by a number that's dependable on the width of the elements*/
}
```

Also, you might have to state the property

```
position:relative;
```

since this seems to be neccesary sometimes (kindof a weird thing in css if you ask me).

Hope this helped, if you meant something else just say so ;)